# variable initialization

Tags: java, variables

If I am getting an error on a function that a variable *opcode* may not have been initialized, should this be done inside this method or in the beginning of the class.

```
private void compileDo() {
        int endLabel, endLabelLoc, topLabel, opcode;
        accept("do");
        accept("(");
        compileExpr();
        accept(")");
        topLabel = cs.getPos();
        endLabelLoc = cs.emit(opcode, topLabel); 
        compileStatement();

    }
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
int  opcode = 0;
```

opcode  is a local variable and hence, you should initialize within the function.